# To try fix this piece in the register login system

Tags: python

Basically, I'm trying to create an id for my login system and for some reason, when I go to add my id thing into there it doesn't seem to work only if I add it in. My goal was to make it so it will go from 0001, 0002, 0003 etc but I don't know how to do it. I want to add the id before create_user

I've tried all different ways like adding int into the code line

```
f.write(create_user + ' : ' + create_pass + "\n")

def register():

    createid = (random.randint(1000, 2000))
    create_user = input("Create your username: ")
    create_pass = input("Create your password: ")
    f = open("users.txt" , "a")
    f.write(create_user + ' : ' + create_pass + "\n")
    f.close
```

When I put put the code

```
f.write(createid, create_user + ' : ' + create_pass + "\n")
```

it comes up with in visual studio code

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
>   write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
>    File "D:\Desktop\python\login.py", line 33, in register
>      f.write(createid, create_user + ' : ' + create_pass + "\n")
>    File "D:\Desktop\python\login.py", line 20, in start
>      register()
>    File "D:\Desktop\python\login.py", line 94, in 
>      start()

Comment: Should `createid` really be selected randomly ? Shouldn't it be incremental  ? So that every user will have a unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def register():
    createid = random.randint(1000, 2000)
    create_user = input("Create your username: ")
    create_pass = input("Create your password: ")

    with  open("users.txt" , "a") as f:
        f.write("{} : {} : {}\n".format(createid, create_user, create_pass))
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked :) I've also just learnt something new :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, please accept the answer if it solved you problem.